# How can I install Mac OS on my MacBook running Linux Mint?

Tags: mac, usb, unix, recovery

I am new here and I hope that this is the right place to find an answer.

My questin is: How can I install a new copy of OS X on my Mac, using Linux?

I recently bought a Macbook Pro from a friend. I am not sure what's the exact model. This friend installed Windows XP on the mac (I don't know how exactly) and that's it. Nothing else is on the HDD. I tried to boot into recovery mode - doesn't work. I tried to boot into internet recovery - nothing happens. I tried Safe boot by pressing Shift Key - nothing happens.

I created a bootable USB using another Windows PC - doesn't show up when I press C or option key. 
The only thing that show's up when I press the option key is a HDD icon named Windows with an arrow under it. If I click it, it takes me to Windows XP, which I cannot use properly. The only thing I was able to do is to install Linux Mint 14 from an old DVD, which works ok except I don't have Wi-Fi.

I've tried different USB sticks, created with Transmac or power iso or with terminal in Linux but nothing showing up the USB so I can boot from. 
Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution for your problem may be the creation of a bootable USB using another Mac computer.

In this way the formatting (`Mac OS Extended`) of the drive will be compatible with Mac systems and it show up when you press C with option key. Then, following the steps you can erase the disk (removing Linux) and install the OS X that you desired.

Comment: Is it more likely to succeed in installing os x if I burn the .dmg image to a DL dvd ?

Comment: @user171437 you can use either USB or DVD. But I think the procedure with USB will be easily implementable.

Comment: I understand, it's just that for now I don't have another mac. So I think that  I will install windows 7 on the Mac,and then run Virtualbox to make the usb bootable in Mac OS.

Comment: @OvidiuLoss ok if you want proceed with a Virtual Machine maybe Linux Mint can work better than Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to obtain a copy of Mac OS X (which ever version you want or is supported by the laptop) and making a bootable USB which would allow you to install it. However the downside being that might only been done from another Mac ( I say might since there could be alternate ways that I don't know yet) 
I'd do a little more research on the subject and see if taking it to an Apple Store is a possibility.